# How do you explain the use of studying higher mathematics to non-mathematicians?

Tags: soft-question, advice

Currently, I am an undergraduate studying math and will soon be taking my first courses at a graduate level. I'm often approached by my friends, my parents, or others, with an innocuous question: "What do you learn by studying math?" Often, I respond with something I'm sure will appeal to the pragmatic nature of their question:

- "It develops strong deductive skills."
- "It treats every problem by its unseen assumptions."

While these answers are ostensibly true, they don't really portray the beauty of an elegant solution. I feel that by studying mathematics, I can really *know* something. Unlike English, or even History, Mathematics' acknowledgements of its extremely basic assumptions makes me feel like I'm discovering something universally true. Of course, this hand-wavy, feeling-based argument doesn't really sate my questioners' curiosity. Moreover, sometimes my audience doesn't know what lies beyond their high school Calculus class, that math can be more than arithmetic; for these folk, it is especially hard to explain the uses of math.

**I guess what I'm asking is**: How might I respond to these questions in a way that doesn't make me trivialize or compromise the deeper aspects of math?

Comment: Tell them that beauty and elegance are parts of mathematics and that you enjoy at least these two aspects.

Comment: This is not terribly on topic here.  Both tags, for one, are inappropriate.  One reason for closure as off topic is "seeking personal advice", and another reason for closure, is "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: I think one studies mathematics for the same reason as one reads or writes poems: the bedazzlement of a sudden discovery.

Comment: Very nicely put, @Bernard.  And, like artists and poets, the bedazzlement of a success in a new (creation) construction, built of the constructions using the framework of mathematics.

Comment: That's why I think mathematics is not really a science.

Comment: Highly related, on Interpersonal SE: [How to deal politely with people asking about your job but unable to understand it?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/3213/1919) (It's about math.)  And probably related: [How to tell family members that they should not downplay your major?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/2516/1919)

Comment: I believe that is using metaphors in your explanation, about the form (I am saying the notion of form of the ancient Greeks, because I think that mathematics is about pure forms). **Example:** You can say *in a same way that Chemistry study molecules or crystals looking at them from different sides using as tools symmetries, then a group is a good set of such tools*. And *with this bag of tools* (for example the de Rham cohomology) *one can dilucidate what is the shape of some figures because doing reasonings or carpentry with this bag of tools one knows what kind of holes have such figures*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing I've noticed about mathematics (and, to an extent, the sciences*) is that they train you to trust a large number of deductive links over a small number of intuitive ones.  In his *Gödel, Escher, Bach*, Doug Hofstadter gives a proof of the commutativity of addition, starting from some basic postulates (not Peano, but something akin to Peano, if I recall correctly).  It occupies something like fifty-six separate lines, almost every one relying in some way on the previous ones.

That is not something that would convince most people.  I assume most people, to the extent that they've thought about addition, have never thought about it not commuting, and if they had, they would treat the fact of it actually commuting as something so obvious as to defy proof.  But in addition, they would treat fifty-six steps as being way too long to be convincing.

Mathematics trains us to consider fifty-six steps as no less rigorous than six, even if we can hold all of the latter in our head, but not the former.  Part of the reason is that the fifty-six steps have an overarching structure, with maybe six "paragraphs" that each have their own "intent."  It is at that level that the intuition of commutative addition is represented, even though the rigor is represented at a lower, line-by-line level.

Another aspect of mathematics that does not occur to many people is the degree to which it unifies concepts.  This too is something it shares to an extent with the sciences.  Whether it is something as trivial as unifying combinatorics and probability, or as deep as the bond between Fermat's last theorem and modular forms, there is an interconnectedness between things that is fundamental to doing mathematics.  More often than in any field, I feel, it achieves that interconnectedness.  It is the substance of analogies—what are the connections, say, between the colonization of China and that of the U.S. colonies?—made exact, made (again) rigorous.

Finally, I remember reading one of Isaac Asimov's essays in the *Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, in which he describes his conception of science and mathematics: like a fractal, so that no matter how closely, how finely you look at it, you see as much complexity at the fine level as you saw at the coarse level.  That is something you can appreciate, I think, only after doing lots and lots of mathematics.  The fact that after thousands of years of humans doing mathematics, we haven't come any closer to exhausting the field—that we have in fact much more to do than at any other time in history—is something that, when I think hard on it, seems almost miraculous.  Why should something so pure, so fundamental, be at the same time so rich?  That's something I don't have anything approaching a good answer for, but I appreciate it.

---

*It's been pointed out, in the comments, that this is not something shared only by mathematics and the hard sciences.  My attribution was based only on my limited experience with stuff outside that arena.  I should not have implied the exclusion of other fields.

Comment: Mathematics is poetry. True poetry ...

Comment: Isham  That's a very Romantic conceptualization, one that many laymen may very well attribute to the stereotypical  mathematician who lives with his/her head always in the clouds.  I think the asker would like to have a way to simply hint on that aspect **in a way that others (non-mathematicians, like family members, e.g.) can understand.**  They may never understand fully, one's passion, and why,  and most of us have to accept that there are going to be people, who either cannot understand the attraction to math, or who simply won't try to understand.  That's not unique to mathematics.

Comment: @Isham  Look up platonism and constuctivism under the umbrella of "philosophy of math".  (Also applies in philosophy):  and exhibited in expressions like "I discovered xyz" (where xyz exists independently of human minds), or as in:  "I constructed (built from a basic framework that one makes clear is based on the tenuous  acceptance regarding what the basic axioms we can only assume). etc.  Any way, ignore my pathetic attempt to make a distinction, But I think you'd be interested in googling, e.g. Platonism vs. Constructivism.

Comment: @amWhy Yep really interested thanks for the suggestion...Will make some search on the topic you proposed

Comment: @Brian "***Another aspect of mathematics that does not occur to many people is the degree to which it unifies concepts. This too is something it shares to an extent with the hard sciences,***" and psychology, and sociology, political science, philosophy etc, who jointly seek unified concepts and constructions. This desire for unification is not a phenomenon unique to mathematician, nor just to the hard sciences.

Comment: @Brian  I would also say that people learn, conceptualize, deep mathematics not based solely on having been trained to do so.  There's no factory model for training folks how to to read, interpret, think of, conform to an entity called mathematics.  I.e., mathematicians are not manufactured through training alone;  Mathematics is born from the interaction of human industry, persistence, inspiration, curiosity, with the inherited creations of our predecessors.

Comment: @amWhy: Fair points.  I'm just not adequately familiar with non-hard sciences to say.  I'll clarify that in my answer.  As for training, I guess in my experiences, people who have not been trained in mathematics don't tend to trust long derivations, or to have seen enough mathematics as to perceive its seeming bottomlessness.  That's what I was referring to.  Maybe some people can see it without that training, but I have not seen it.

Comment: I must say, this is not the response I expected, but I am glad you gave it. Implicit in my statement was some self-doubt too; I think you've given a good argument for curiosity instead.

Comment: I disagree with your explanation of rigor and mathematical proofs.  I have [earlier elaborated on this point in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39899812#39899812).  Incidentally, I have seen mathematics unflatteringly defined as (paraphrased) "a system of 'vias' (indirection) whereby one can symbolically derive an answer without having to know it" and your description seems to fit this definition.

Comment: @Wildcard: Hmm.  I think one can *verify* a derivation without having to know it, but I think that humans, at least, don't typically *arrive* at them in that fashion.  Of course, the derivation in *GEB* is not intended to be representative of how mathematics gets done, just what a rigorous derivation in a particular axiomatic system might look like.

But yours is an interesting and different viewpoint.  Will you be writing an answer to this question?

Comment: @BrianTung, I like your distinction between verification of a proof and arrival at knowingness; it seems we agree.  Arrival at a *derivation* can be accomplished without fully knowing it, though, or it would be impossible to write a false proof and believe you'd solved something; e.g. published "proofs" reviewed for years before discovery of counterexamples show that full knowingness of the result had not taken place.  But this discussion is definitely epistemology, not its subfield "mathematics."  ;)  I think my viewpoint, while interesting, doesn't answer *this* question, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer the hidden presumption that this question takes for granted rather than the popular answer or list of quotes from great mathematicians.

Mathematics is a tool. One of many in your arsenal. It is based on deductive logic but it is not a synonym of deductive logic, rather a broad subset.

As for the question of elegance or beauty, remember that form follows the function. Beauty and elegance is derived by the purpose. Nothing is elegant in  a vacuum nor does a tool automatically gain elegance by majority vote.

Other than that, Maths is great. Even greater is that you enjoy it. Just keep the automagical presumptions of elegance at bay and prove it's elegance by application if you can.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you think certain people have their priorities misplaced if they feel a sense of elegance or beauty in some piece of mathematics, removed from any application?  Incidentally, I would not consider mathematics a subset of deductive logic.  Derivations might be, but there is more to mathematics than deductive logic, I think.

Comment: Priorities misplaced? no. Undeveloped and/or static sense of beauty... maybe... I won't argue though. This is a Q&A site and that is a dangerously open ended discussion.